# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/tmatesoft/sqljet/core/SqlJetException

Tags: java

I was trying to get the `SVN project` to my local directory. But I am getting Exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/tmatesoft/sqljet/core/SqlJetException
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.SVNWCContext.<init>(SVNWCContext.java:278)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.SVNWCContext.<init>(SVNWCContext.java:274)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.obtainWcContext(SvnOperationFactory.java:1269)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1232)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:291)
at down.main(down.java:20)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.SqlJetException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 6 more
```

Thank you

Comment: Well, it looks like your sqljet jar file isn't in the classpath. Unfortunately you've given us *no* context other than the exception, so we can't really help you fix it.

Comment: @user3064366 if my answer is helpful you can upvote and select my answer

Answer (score 2):

Required **jar(sqljet.jar)** is not their in your **classpath**
you can download jar from this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/sqljet/sqljet.jar.zip) and then set your **classpath**.